# Python subprocess.Popen change folder permission?

Tags: python, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, I use `subprocess.Popen` to call an executable file, which will save some output files on the hard drive of server. The code has been tested successfully on a Local machine. However, it does not work on the server. My code is listed below:

```
#create a new folder. The permission is drwxrwx both locally and on the server end
os.makedirs(folder)

#copy the executable file to this folder. The permission is drwxrwx both locally and on the server end after copy
shutil.copy("a.exe", folder)

#call this exe file. The permission is drwxrwx locally but changed to drwxr-x on the server end. Since I do not have the write permit, my code fails.
subprocess.Popen("a.exe")
```

I am not sure why subprocess changes my folder permission on the server end. So can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You do have quotes around `a.exe` in `shutil.copy` in your actual code, right?

Comment: Yes. The statement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
subprocess.Popen("a.exe", shell=True)
```

Comment: I have tried shell=True. Same problem, however both approaches work on a local machine. Thanks